# Thymeleaf: Default message from messageKey

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I want to set the default message of a translation. But I can only do this by writing the text directly into the template.

The translation of the default message can be done with `#{default-message}`. I can't find anything about this in the [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#messages-1).

```html
<span th:text="${#messages.msgOrNull('') ?: 'My default Message'}"/>
// Output: "My default Message"
```

I have made many attempts. For example, the following. But it always returns a 500 or is not transformed.

```html
<span th:text="${#messages.msgOrNull('') ?: #{default-message}}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest expressions like this: `${... #{...}}` -- move the second expression outside the first, like this:

```
<span th:text="${#messages.msgOrNull('')} ?: #{default-message}"/>
```

You can see other examples of these kinds of expressions in the [Thymeleaf documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator).